# Text under 'overbrace' too big

Tags: braces, size, overbrace

I have an equation, and one part of it is under an 'overbrace'. The problem is the numbers under the brace are too big. When I only write the part with the overbrace the size is fine. Is there any way this could be fixed? Thanks a lot!
Code and picture attached

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt[n]{n} =^{(1)} \sqrt[n]{n \cdot 1^{n-1}} =\sqrt[n]{n \cdot 
\smash[b]{\underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{n-1~times}
}} <^{(2)} \frac{n+\overbrace{1+\ldots+1}^{n-1~ times}}{n}=\frac{n+(n-1)}{n}=\frac{2n-1}{n}=2-\frac{1}{n}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is coded as inline math, which is why the fraction is sized for text.  Will this really be used within text, or will it be a display?  Coding it as a display should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the Knuth's macro `\overbrace` (used in Plain TeX) declares explicitly `\displaystyle` for its argument, see line 959 of the plain.tex file. LaTeX, unfortunately, takes this idea too.

Solution: you can use Unicode Math, because Unicode Math declares `\overbrace` in completely different and better way. Or, you must explicitly say `\scriptstyle` in the argument of `\overbrace`. But this is poor solution: when you decide to switch your formula from inline math `$...$` to display `$$...$$` then you have to remove this `\scriptstyle` command. Best solution: use Uncode Math (for example OpTeX uses Unicode Math, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX are able to use Unicode Math too).

Comment: Not sure if the issue you're discussing is what's actually plaguing the OP. I thought it was that `$n-1$ times` -- which *is* typeset at `\scriptsize`-- was wider than the horizontal curly brace right above it.

Comment: @Mico OP used inline math, so the fraction has numerator, denominator in `\sriptstyle`. OP refers, that the digits "1" is bigger in the nominator. Note the picture.  Of course, OP has a few mistakes in the code and you corrected them in your answer, but the core of the question is: digits "1" are bigger when inline math is used.

Comment: Thanks. You're absolutely right, and it is *my* working assumption regarding the nature of the OP's issue that's in error. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @wipet now that Mico has deleted their answer I can't see what the mistakes in my code are, do you perhaps remember what they were?

Comment: @tcb try to ask to Mico to undelete the answer. The answer doesn't solve directly the main problem but it is usable too. Mico used `\mathclap` in the argument of underbrace because "n-1 times" is wider than "1...1".  He used \rm font (\text macro) for the text "times". He used `\dots` instead `\ldots` between "+" symbols. He used `\vphantom` after `\sqrt` in order to set correct depth of the whole formula.

Comment: @Mico -- As requested by wipet, please undelete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ the `mathtools` package (which, incidentally, loads the `amsmath` package automatically) and use its `\mathclap` macro.

Oh, and don't forget to insert a `\vphantom` directive to make up for the depth lost because of the `\smash[b]{\sqrt{...}}` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt[n]{n} 
=^{(1)} \sqrt[n]{n \cdot 1^{n-1}} 
=\sqrt[n]{n \cdot \smash[b]{
   \underbrace{1\cdots 1}_{ \mathclap{\text{$n-1$ times}} }}} 
   \vphantom{\underbrace{1}_{1}}
<^{(2)} \frac{n+\overbrace{1+\dots+1}^{\text{$n-1$ times}}}{n}
=\frac{n+(n-1)}{n}=\frac{2n-1}{n}=2-\frac{1}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```